# How should I const inside function when refactoring to class in Javascript

Tags: javascript, es6-class

Assuming I have a function that is used as a class:

```js
function Builder() {
  const a = somethingThatReturnsAnArray();
  this.b = somethingThatReturnsAnotherArray();

  this.foo = () => {
    a.push('test');
    this.b.push('test');
  }
}

// Later...

const builder = new Builder();
builder.foo();
```

Is there any difference between declaring `a` as a const and `b` attached to `this`? Can I convert this function to the class below?

```js
class Builder {
  constructor() {
    this.a = somethingThatReturnsAnArray();
    this.b = somethingThatReturnsAnotherArray();
  }

  foo() {
    this.a.push('test');
    this.b.push('test');
  }
}
```

If so is there some caveats in converting everything to class properties?

I guess converting `const b = ...` to `this.b` will have some pitfalls, but I'm not sure. What is the correct way to do this? In other words, how should I const inside function when refactoring to class in Javascript?

Comment: One difference is you can access `b` on an instance of `Builder` like `builder.b`, but you don't have access to `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` should be private in class.

```js
class Builder {
  #a = somethingThatReturnsAnArray();

  constructor() {
    this.b = somethingThatReturnsAnotherArray();
  }

  foo() {
    this.#a.push('test');
    this.b.push('test');
  }
}
```